# horizontal addthis widget stacks vertically only in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, addthis

Example: [www.dirtycookie.co](http://dirtycookie.co)

Look at both Firefox (or any other browser) and Safari.

Firefox has the desired behavior.

Here is my AddThis code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="text-align:center;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"     addthis:url="http://www.facebook.com/TheDirtyCookie"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:url="http://www.dirtycookie.co"    pi:pinit:layout="horizontal" always-show-count="1" pi:pinit:size="small"></a> 
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon_badge"></a>  
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is happening in my Chrome...looks like float definition is getting overwritten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening on Chrome too (latest)..

your CSS and Widget CSS(addThis) is getting conflicted.... 
.....Overwrite it by adding this in your style.css:

```
.addthis_default_style .addthis_separator, 
.addthis_default_style .at300b, 
.addthis_default_style .at300bo, 
.addthis_default_style .at300m, 
.addthis_default_style .at300bs {
    float: left !important;
}
```